# How to apply compatplaylist to HwCertTestCollection

Tags: windows, powershell

For HLK testing automation I would like to apply the compatplaylist on my test list.

Generell automation [instruction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/hlk/user/hlk-automation-tool), but no info how to apply a playlist.

One option is to modify the master test list based on the compatplaylist - both are xml based (with the help of Export-HwCertTestCollectionToXml and import-hwcerttestcollectionfromxml),

But maybe somebody already has a solution or knows an offical support for it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
    public static PlaylistManager ApplyPlaylist(Project projectname, string playlistpath)
    {
        PlaylistManager pl_manager = null;
        try
        {
            pl_manager = new PlaylistManager(projectname);
            if (pl_manager == null)                
                Console.WriteLine("Cannot make playlist manager for the project:- {0}", projectname.Name.ToString());

            if(pl_manager.IsPlaylistLoaded() == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Playlist loaded.. unloading ");
                pl_manager.UnloadPlaylist();
                if (pl_manager.IsPlaylistLoaded() == false)
                    Console.WriteLine("Unloaded successfully");
            }
            else
            {
                if (File.Exists(playlistpath))
                { 
                    pl_manager.LoadPlaylist(playlistpath);
                    if (pl_manager.IsPlaylistLoaded() == false)
                        Console.WriteLine("Error in applying playlist:- {0}", playlistpath);
                    else
                        Console.WriteLine("Loaded playlist:- {0}", playlistpath);
                }

                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("ERROR!Playlist file {0} not found!", playlistpath);
                    return pl_manager;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception:-{0}", e.ToString());
        }

        return pl_manager;
    }
```